# ReadOnly/Formula Field on edit page - Lightning

Tags: lightning, formula, read-only, spring16, edit

I have a question about read-only/formula fields on the edit page in Lightning.

Previously the fields of Read-Only/Formula were not available on the edit page, however in Spring'16 they have included this feature. I have read the documentation about Spring'16 but did not manage to find how to turn off/hide formula fields on the edit page of a custom object.

So how to turn off/hide formula fields on a custom object in lightning?

As a developer i have some ways to fix this, however i'm not sure this would be the optimal way.